# Django: Excluding objects from Same Model

Tags: python, django

Here's my code,

```
objects = Games.objects.filter(...)[:5]
items = Games.objects.exclude("Exclude all 5 "GAMES" contained in variable 'objects')
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`__in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#in):

```
objects = Games.objects.filter(...)[:5]
items = Games.objects.exclude(pk__in=objects)
```

Some databases may not let you use a limit in a subquery. In that case, you can covert the `objects` queryset to a list:

```
objects = list(Games.objects.filter(...)[:5])
items = Games.objects.exclude(pk__in=objects)
```

Note that in Django it's recommended to use the singular `Game` for your model name.

Comment: Working perfectly fine. Thank you very much Sir :)